# Is it possible to sort rows by values from generate_series()?

Tags: postgresql, order-by, set-returning-functions, cross-join

I multiply result rows of a `SELECT` with `CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, max)`. My query is like:

```
select id, name
from person
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, 4)
where <condition>;
```

I have this result:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 |
| 1 | name1 |
| 1 | name1 |
| 1 | name1 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 3 | name3 |
| 3 | name3 |
| 3 | name3 |
| 3 | name3 |

I want the result like this:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 3 | name3 |
| 1 | name1 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 3 | name3 |
| 1 | name1 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 3 | name3 |
| 1 | name1 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 3 | name3 |

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, `ORDER BY` expressions do not have to be listed in the `SELECT` list.
Order by the generated value, then by whatever else you want to order by:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name
FROM   person p
CROSS  JOIN generate_series(1, 4) g(g)
WHERE  p.id < 4       -- or whatever
ORDER  BY g.g, p.id;  --  !!!
```

Or, with minimal syntax (less safe against ambiguous identifiers):

```
SELECT id, name
FROM   person, generate_series(1, 4) g
WHERE  id < 4     -- or whatever
ORDER  BY g, id;  --  !!!
```

Comment: Just thought I'd mention "`ORDER BY` expressions do not have to be listed in the `SELECT` list" except when `DISTINCT` is used (which it isn't here)